# vote-function "No Eintrag matches the given query"

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, ajax, django

**I want to implement a vote function. The vote function can't get the object. vote.js should be okay. Any idea? It seems that the POST request isn't send. Thank you.**

This is the error:

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://.../vote/
Raised by:  book.views.vote
No Eintrag matches the given query.
```

snippet in result.html:

```
<a href="/vote/" id="eintrag-vote-{{ eintrag.id }}" class="vote">▲</a>
<p id="eintrag-title-{{ eintrag.id }}">{{ eintrag.title }}</p>
```

models.py:

```
class Eintrag(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, default=1)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    points = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    text = models.TextField()
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def vote(request):
    eintrag = get_object_or_404(Eintrag, id=request.POST.get('eintrag'))
    eintrag.points += 1
    eintrag.save()
    return HttpResponse()
```

urls.py:

```
url(r'^vote/$', views.vote, name='vote'),
```

and vote.js:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // using jQuery
  function getCookie(name) {
    var cookieValue = null;
    if (document.cookie && document.cookie != '') {
      var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
        var cookie = jQuery.trim(cookies[i]);
        // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
        if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) == (name + '=')) {
          cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    return cookieValue;
  }
  var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');

  function.vote(eintragID) {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "/vote/",
      data: {
        "eintrag": eintragID
      },
      success: function() {
        $("#eintrag-vote-" + eintragID).hide();
        $("#eintrag-title-" + eintragID).css({
          "margin-left": "15px"
        });
      },
      headers: {
        'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
      }
    });
    return false;
  }

  $("a.vote").click(function() {
    var eintragID = parseInt(this.id.split("-")[2]);
    return vote(eintragID);
  })

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have a request method mismatch. You are doing a GET when you should be doing a POST.

This line raises a 404 because there is no `request.POST`:

```
eintrag = get_object_or_404(Eintrag, id=request.POST.get('eintrag'))
```

I invite you to decorate this view with `django.views.decorators.http.require_POST` so you get an `HTTP 405 Method not allowed error` that better reflects the method issue than a 404

I think it comes from how your Ajax request is done in JS (see http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/)

Can you try changing the following?

```
function vote(eintragID) {
  $.ajax({
    ...
```

Comment: Same error: the PuttY says: Not Found: /vote/
[12/Jun/2016 18:17:15] "GET /vote/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1722

Comment: Well, You'll always have a problem if you do a GET request, you have to change it to a POST request somehow. Don't forget to collectstatic after you've changed your JS file.

Comment: `code` function.vote (eintragID) {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "/vote/",
        data: {"eintrag": eintragID},
        success: function() {
            $("#eintrag-vote-" + eintragID).hide();
            $("#eintrag-title-" + eintragID).css({"margin-left": "15px"});
        },
        headers: {
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        }
    });
    return false;
} `code`

Comment: where should I change it?  It already shoud be a POST request, but the server keeps saying GET

Comment: Make sure you invalidate the cache on your browser and that you are using the latest version of your JS file. Check the network tab to see what request is actually sent to the server. Also, I invite you to decorate your view with `django.views.decorators.http.require_POST` so you get an HTTP error code that best reflects the problem you have.

Comment: alright i changed the vote function and added @require_POST. so now the network tab says: Method Not Allowed (GET): /vote/ and I get a blank page now.

Comment: It still does a GET request, although it should be a POST request .

Comment: The Ajax function is probably never called and clicking just opens the link in the `<a>`, try removing the dot between `function`  and `vote`.

Comment: thank you so much! wow it was just a dot :D have a nice day! :)

Comment: I suppose you might have been able to spot it from the JS/browser console logs.